# How is my singing?

Tags: voice

Am I good enough for busking and open mics? I am also a song writer and wishing to record an EP soon. Am I good enough though? Would value some honest feedback :)

Comment: Since this question is looking for opinions, please open it in the chat room, which is designed for discussion.

Comment: One way to determine how good you are is to actually sing for strangers who aren’t musicians and see how they react. As in go ahead and busk and go to open mikes and see what happens

Comment: @Aaron Isn’t chat only available after a certain rep?

Comment: The first step is to continue participating on the main site by asking or answering questions until your reputation is 20 or more. That's the required level to begin participating in the chat rooms.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a moment to read about the [topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). The "20 rep" needed to join the chat room can be gained with just a few good questions or answers.

Comment: As Todd says, get out and sing. Open mics are a great way to start in public, and very different from singing in the bedroom or making a recording. And you won't need any gear - apart from guitar, which sounds fine.